# Not allowing to inherit from some class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I came across with the following program in `C++`:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
    Foo() {};
    friend T;
};
class Bar : public virtual Foo<Bar> {
     void doPrivateStuff();
public:
     template<typename T>
     void baz(T a) { cout << a << endl; }
};
```

It says that using this way it is not possible to inheritance from `Bar`. I have two questions:

- What makes the compiler to not allow to inherit from `Bar`?
- Can I inherit it virtually?
- I know that `friend` is used to declare a method or a class which can access the private fields and methods of the class, but what does `friend T` mean?

It is based on the following page:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the message from the compiler?

Comment: [I can inherit from `Bar` just fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lStGWIDwMpTVQYM0)

Comment: @AndyG -- now try to instantiate "`Baz baz;`"
 in `main()`, and see what happens.

Comment: @AndyG Try to declare a constructor. I guess because `bar` is a template class, it will not initialize it until it will be use, that is why your example compiles.

Answer (score 1):

A virtually inherited class always becomes a direct superclass of the most derived class. In other words, anything that inherits from `Bar` will ***directly*** inherit from `Foo<Bar>`. That's what virtual inheritance means.

However, `Foo<Bar>` has a private constructor, and only `Bar` is the class's `friend`, as such only `Bar` can inherit from `Foo<Bar>`.

This effectively prevents declaring a subclass of `Baz`, because that subclass must virtually inherit the template class, but it can't construct it, because the inherited constructor is private.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to add on how its possible to pass it with the C++ template specialization feature?

Comment: A virtual base does not automatically become a direct base class of the most derived class. The most derived class will **construct** it, but aside from that it still has its normal place in the class hierarchy. `struct B { int i; }; struct C : virtual B { int i; }; struct D : C { }; D d; d.i = 3;` That assignment assigns to the `i` in the `C` base and not to the one in the `B` base. Virtual inheritance means that **multiple** virtual bases of the same type get merged into a single subobject that’s shared by all the base subobjects that have that virtual base.